# How common is it for mobile network operators to give the same IPv4 address to different 3G devices?

Tags: ipv4, ip, nat, ip-address, mobile

Do they have to give different IPv4 addresses?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possible. This type of NAT is called Carrier grade NAT (CG-NAT) and is supported by most vendor (Juniper, Cisco Alcatel) equipment.

Answer (score 2):

If the carrier uses NAT, the carrier can reuse addresses in different locations.  This is how home networks can all reuse the same subnet and addresses.

NAT masks the assigned address behind a globally unique address.